# geojson generated from mysql not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a function in php:

```
 public static function getGeoJSON() {
 // code that generates geojson from mysql
  return $geojson;
 }
```

In javascript i call this function:

```
     var geo = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($geo) ?>' );

    //this is where I want to put my generated geojson instead of a file.geojson

  d3.json('point.geojson', function(geojson){
    mapDraw(geojson);
    });
```

like this I want it:

```
  // replace static file with generated geojson
  d3.json(geo, function(geojson){
    mapDraw(geojson);
    });
```

I have printed the generated geojson and pasted it into a json file and it works. but when I try to put the

```
 var geo
```

as reference instead of the path it fails. Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

```
    {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[xx.xxx,xx.xxx]},"properties":{"description":"bad description"}}]}
```

Comment: what is the content of the `$geo` variable? how does this geojson string looks like?

Comment: It fails because that's not how the `d3.json()` function works.  It expects/requires the first argument to be a path to a file.

Comment: I edited the OP, with a working generated json string.

Patrick Q: do you have any idea how I can get it to work with d3?

Comment: i foudn out. just call mapdraw without the d3.js function